# Wordpress change <title> ... </title> from a plugin (without template edit)

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, title

I have made a google search about this but i did not find any answer

Is it possible to change the wordpress title without template edit?

I want to change

```
<title> Change this from a wp plugin  </title>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a plugin file and paste the code below...

```
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'custom_title', 20 );

function custom_title( $title ) {
    return  'New title';
}
```